# If $T,S$ are positive operators, does $T^{1/2}S^{1/2} = S^{1/2}T^{1/2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we let  $V$ be a finite dim. real/ complex inner product space, and $T \in L(V)$ and $S \in L(V)$ we let be positive operators,  does $T^{1/2}S^{1/2} = S^{1/2}T^{1/2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Positive matrix" (Operator) has two meanings (all coefficients are positive/non-negative or positive-definite, but in either case the answer is NO. Just make some random example and see for yourself!